# I cant able to show ui:inputselect value from database?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I cant able to show  "{!v.BatchInstance.Discount_Type__c}" value in ui:inputselect??

Outside of ui:inputselect it is showing the value .this value is retrieving from the database

```
{!v.BatchInstance.Discount_Type__c}/*here the values it is displaying.*/
         <td>
            <ui:inputselect class="slds-input" value="{!v.BatchInstance.Discount_Type__c}" aura:id="disctype" change="{!c.discountvalidation}">
             <option value=""> - </option> 
             <option value="ServicePremium"> ServicePremium </option> 
             <option value="Service Rapide"> Service Rapide </option> 
              <option value="MOD/MOQ">     MOD/MOQ </option> 

             </ui:inputselect>   
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<ui:inputselect class="slds-input" value="{!v.BatchInstance.Discount_Type__c}" aura:id="disctype" change="{!c.discountvalidation}">
                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="" label="-"/> 
                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="ServicePremium" label="ServicePremium"/> 
                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Service Rapide" label="Service Rapide"/> 
                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="MOD/MOQ" label="MOD/MOQ"/> 

                    </ui:inputselect>
```